# CSS Background-image not loading on mobile safari when using absolute URL

Tags: html, css

**CSS**

```
  #header {
    background: url('https://somecdn.com/myapp/public/img/mobile/header.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    width: 640px !important;
    position: relative;
    height: 98px;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">...</div>
```

This works fine on any other browser, but on my friend's mobile safari (works on mine), it doesn't.  When we looked in the developer tool after connecting the phone to a mac, it shows that the browser loads the url as **http://domainname.com**https://somecdn.com/myapp/public/img/mobile/header.jpg, so basically it is interpreting the absolute url as relative path...  What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened. As you can see in my post. Our site is NOT on https, but the asset was. Most browsers handled this gracefully, but this particular mobile browser did not handle it. We simply used http version of assets and all is well... – Ryan Her 45 secs ago edit